# How to converse Markdown file to HTML in PowerShell without any error and in a clean way?

Tags: powershell

so I have updated my PowerShell (downloaded new one from MS Store) to version 7.2.4.0.

And the I wantto convert Markdown file to HTML, so I would import the 2 modules based on this description (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30591.convert-markdown-to-html-using-powershell.aspx), so I would do something like:

1. Import-Module C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\powershellMarkdown.dll
   Import-Module C:\Users\mitus\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MarkdownSharp.dll
2. Now I want to:

   ```
   $md = ConvertFrom-Markdown C:\test\test.md
   ```

   It results with:

   ```
   ConvertFrom-Markdown: The given key 'test.md' was not present in the dictionary.
   ```
3. So I try the following:

   ```
   $md = ConvertFrom-Markdown -Path .\test.md
   ```

   And the POwerShell now says:

   ```
   ConvertFrom-Markdown: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Path'.
   ```

   Either way, Its not working. Why PowerShell does not know parameter -Path? How do I make conversion from Markup to HTML working? Why is this shit not working at all even if imported those two .dll files? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ConvertFrom-*` commands generally don't support file input directly (with exceptions). When there is no related `Import-*` command, you have to use `Get-Content` to first read the file and then pass it to the `ConvertFrom-*` command like so:

```sh
$md = Get-Content C:\test\test.md -Raw | ConvertFrom-Markdown
```

Make sure to use the `-Raw` parameter so the `ConvertFrom-Markdown` command receives a single input string instead of an array of lines, which could be parsed incorrectly.

If you want to inspect the content of the `.md` file first, you may store it in a separate variable:

```sh
$text = Get-Content C:\test\test.md -Raw

# Now you may optionally log the content of the .md file
Write-Host $text

$md = $text | ConvertFrom-Markdown
```

Comment: That works great, although I decided to use Markdown plugin in VSCode as It seems It's got better formatting.. But thanks